# Why my app is not available for my device in android market?

Tags: android, filter, tablet, google-play

I'm lost. 
I have a chinese tablet ([CubeU10GT-S](http://www.chinatabletspcs.com/Cube-U10GT-8-Android-2-3-Tablet-PC-Capacitive-RK2918-Cortex-A8-1-2GHz-512MB-DDR3-2-Cameras-Flash10-1-aPad.html)) with Android 2.3.1 (wifi only,1024*768). I developed an app which was tested on this device as well. But uploaded on market it's not compatible with my tablet (and might be with a lot of similar ones)...
I request minimal set of permissions/features - can anyone tell me why appstore filters out my tablet?

Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="indigowind.spyprofile"
      android:versionCode="4"
      android:versionName="1.3">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"/>

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false">
        <activity 
            android:name="SpyProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity            
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
        />
    </application>

    <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"  />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Google didn't tell you why?  More to the point...have you asked them?

Comment: you mean support? I haven't asked them yet... and i don't believe they will answer anything except "check the guidelines". Otherwise there wouldn't be similar questions on the forums. Even here there are several questions alike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have switch off the protection from copying. When I did it (and a couple of hours passed), my app became compatible with 2 my devices (the 3rd one has too old sdk)

Comment: how do you switch off copy protection?