# android play store is filtering my app from tablets, possibly other devices

Tags: android, google-play

I have several versions of an app live on Play, and I'm getting feedback that they don't appear on tablets.  I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768823/android-app-showing-up-in-play-store-search-only-on-certain-devices) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443964/my-app-is-not-available-for-tablet-device-on-google-play) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838604/why-my-app-is-not-available-for-my-device-in-android-market), but as you can see they don't seem to apply.  I explicitly support all screens and mark telephony as non-required, and I don't use copy protection since my app is free to end users.  Can anyone see a problem?

My manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="12.0" package="com.example.app">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- So that tablets, without telephony will not be filtered out by the market. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <supports-screens 
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>


    <application android:name="com.example.app.Application" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.example.app.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.app.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.example.app.NavigationActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: In the APK screen you can see both supported and excluded devices. Is the information there consistent with the devices that are excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, it looks like the few users who couldn't find an app were looking for older apps (without 
    `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>`
in the manifest).  The new apps seem to be fine.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Hey I am running into the same thing. Have you noticed that by adding the support screen tag, you are losing the compatibility mode button for tablets :(. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You have included CALL_PHONE permission.  Most tablets do not provide this feature and will most likely have them filtered out.

See here for additional info/ideas

[android.permission.CALL_PHONE for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882955/android-permission-call-phone-for-tablets)